# How to change/alter the mysql database user

Tags: mysql, database, permissions

I have the mysql database user on server as `rob` and password something like `rob123`

And now i tried to create a database for user `rob`, so i logged in as

```
mysql -u rob -prob123
```

I can able to login successfully and when tried to create a database like below

```
create database hello;
```

i got below error

ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'rob'@'%' to database 'hello'

So i logged in as default mysql user as `root` and logged in successfully

```
mysql -u root
```

Now i can able to create a database with  `create database hello;` , but i need to change the user of this database `'hello'` as `rob` and password as `rob123`.

So how to alter the user of the database ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to create user and grant permissions:

```
use hello;
create user rob identified by 'rob';
grant all on rob.* to 'rob'@'%';
grant select on `mysql`.`proc` to 'rob'@'%';
```

Comment: then make up a new one.  it's an example.  or grant that use permissions to use the new database and tables.